# Swift 3 Firebase - (setValue:) Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at content

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I've seen this question asked multiple times, but can't seem to figure out how to use those answers to solve the problem in my code. This is the current code I'm using:

```
if let postContent = postAlert.textFields?.first?.text {
    let post = Post(content: postContent, addedByUser: "Max Kortge")

    let postRef = self.dbRef.child(postContent.lowercased())

    postRef.setValue(post.toAnyObject()) //error here
}
```

I presume that the error in the console means the line where I've commented 'error here'.

The method toAnyObject is below:

```
func toAnyObject() -> Any {
    return ["content":content, "addedByUser":addedByUser] as Any
}
```

The full console error is below:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at content. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing :-

```
func toAnyObject() -> Any {
  return ["content":content, "addedByUser":addedByUser] as Any
 }
```

To

```
func toAnyObject() -> [AnyHashable:Any] {
  return ["content":content, "addedByUser":addedByUser] as [AnyHashable:Any]
 }
```

Comment: They're both exactly the same?

Answer (score 9):

With version `3.12.0` I got the *Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue* error even though I made sure I sent a NSString and not a swift string. What I did wrong was the format of the completion block. I changed this:

```
ref.child("data").setValue("str")  {
    print("done")
}
```

to this:

```
ref.child("data").setValue("str")  { err, ref in
    print("done")
}
```

Must be a bug and I expect a better error message in a future firebase release.

Comment: I searched for hours.. thank you so much. It's wrong in the examples

Answer (score 1):

make sure 'post' in your code is [String : String] instead of [String : String?]

Comment: This answer does not make sense.  You are saying `post` should be the same.  I think you have a typo in your answer.  Please correct it.